# Machine Key in web.config of mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

We recently migrated our applications to mvc3. With the older versions we needed to have the machine key attribute added to the web.config files to ensure that load balanced servers didn't have view-state encryption errors.

If this still needed in MVC3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is still needed. The encryption infrastructure of .NET hasn't changed.